# How does idiom "Breaks the ice" suits here?

Tags: meaning, idioms

In ***[Red Eye](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0421239/)***, Lisa just met Jackson at airport. actually he is complete stranger to her.
At drinks corner, Jackson's guess nearly came close what Lisa going to order for drink:

> Lisa: It's an impressive talent, though. Very close.
>
> Jackson: You know, **breaks the ice**.

I know "**Breaks the ice**" is idiom which means two strange persons getting relaxed each other, but here context is totally different to used it, he just guess her drink.

Comment: I think your problem might be because the dialogue is made of up sentence fragments. We do use language this way, but it is confusing if it is even slightly out of context. Jackson: "It's just my way of breaking the ice. Cheers!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a way of starting a conversation. Starting a conversation with a stranger - especially where there is a possibility of some level of flirtation - is 'breaking the ice'